Why do all new .desktop launchers go to 2nd page in app menu Ubuntu 22.04?
I like to group apps by category, leaving plenty of open space. I would like to know if I can force new stuff to be placed in the space on the 1st page of the menu.

Getting everything off the 2nd page removes that page then everything new will be put on the 1st page.

That is because it is designed to work this way. New applications are always placed at the end of the existing applications, that means on the last page where there is still place. It is then up to you to organize the icon where you want it to be.
Indeed, if you remove all icons from an earlier page, that page will cease to exist.
